# Difference between android 2.3.3 and android 4.2 enforcing permissions?

Tags: android, user-permissions

I am just playing with a certain scenario of inter-application-communication, 
and trying to circumvent the problem that in Android the main activity of an application 
can't be secured by a custom permisssion (as in that case it can't be launched at all).

I tried to use two activities instead: 1) The main activity which is not protected. 
2) When a button is clicked, the main activity sends an explicit Intent to start the second activity. 
That one performs some sensitive work and is protected by a custom permission
("toy.test.permission.ACTIVATE_SECOND_ACTIVITY").
The idea being that if the main activity is either started by the user from the launcher or 
by a foreign maliscious application using an explicit intent, we can warn the user before he pushes the button to proceed.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
    final Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
    start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent activateIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SecondActivity.class);
            startActivity(activateIntent);
            finish();
        }
    });  ....
```

The Manifest.xml file looks like that:

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>            
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name=".SecondActivity"
        android:label="@string/second_activity_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:permission="toy.test.permission.ACTIVATE_SECOND_ACTIVITY" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="toy.test.action.ACTIVATE_SECOND_ACTIVITY" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>            
</application>
```

(In addition, the SecondActivity can be started from a friend application by an implicit Intent with 
actionString="toy.test.action.ACTIVATE_SECOND_ACTIVITY" using the permission 
"toy.test.permission.ACTIVATE_SECOND_ACTIVITY".)

## Now the difference between android 2.3.3 and android 4.2:

On an android 4.2 device or emulator, the SecondActivity can be started from the MainActivity by clicking 
the Start button without any problems, although the application does not ask explicitly for the permission 
"toy.test.permission.ACTIVATE_SECOND_ACTIVITY".

However, on an android 2.3.3 emulator, the SecondActivity can't be started because of SecurityException:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting Intent { cmp=toy.test/.SecondActivity } 
from ProcessRecord{406827d0 405:toy.test/10034} (pid=405, uid=10034) requires
toy.test.permission.ACTIVATE_SECOND_ACTIVITY
```

I am confused: Was the permission enforcement changed between the two Android versions? 
And is it on purpose that android 4.2 allows such situations, i.e. activation of the SecondActivity without permission?
(Of course, that would be useful.)

Thanks a lot for any answers,
puffin137

Comment: You might want to update your manifest paste into this question to be complete, including the `<permission>` element.

Comment: The friend application's declaration of the permission in its Manifest is like that:   <permission
    android:name="toy.test.permission.ACTIVATE_SECOND_ACTIVITY"
    android:description="@string/activate_activity_permission_description"
    android:label="@string/activate_activity_permission_label"
    android:permissionGroup="android.permission-group.PERSONAL_INFO"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />

Comment: I'd put the `<permission>` element in both apps, not just the one, so installation order becomes less of an issue.